# How to install colormap using pip for Spyder (Python 3.5) on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, spyder, colormap

I want to use cmap_builder, So I tried
`from colormap import cmap_builder`.
When I tried, Spyder throwed me an error
`ImportError: No module named 'colormap'`

So I tried installing, `pip install colormap` as described in http://colormap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
This didn't work and displayed a message
`No matching distribution found`

So is there a different way to install colormap for python 3.5 to use on Spyder ?

Comment: This `colormap` package seems pretty useless. All the tools to create colormaps are actually already built into matplotlib.

Comment: Oh then how to use just matplotlib instead of colormap ?

Comment: I provided an example below. It depends on your case of course and you may update your question with the actual usage case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle matplotlib already has all the tools available to create custom colormaps. The two main options are to create a segmented colormap, `LinearSegmentedColormap` or a discrete colormap `ListedColormap`.

Find here an example of a continuous colormap between crimson, gold and blue:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("n", ["crimson", "gold","steelblue"])

x = np.linspace(-1,2.7)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
Z = np.exp(-X**2-Y**2)

im =plt.imshow(Z, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

A discrete colormap could be created like this:

```
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(["crimson", "gold","steelblue"])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, This works perfectly for me ....I just replaced colormap by cmap with your description